# tfs express 2012 Update 2 ctp 2 to Update 3

Tags: tfs

I am trying to upgrade from tfs express 2012 Update 2 ctp 2 to Update 3. The installation went fine when trying to upgrade the DB i am getting error. I am running Win 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 Express.

"TF255438: The configuration database that you specified cannot be upgraded. The following issue prevents upgrading the database: TF400965: The database was created using a non-Go Live version of Team Foundation Server and cannot be upgraded. upgrade 3"

Now my tfs wont run and i am not sure what to do.. Any quick ideas that would help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any idea on how to get the tfs back up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, uninstall 2012.3 and reinstall your Update 2 CTP 2 version. That will at least get you back up and running.

Next create a 'test tfs' box with a backup of your TFS databases and the 2012.2 CTP 2 installed and try upgrading that to 2012.2 and see if it works - you can still download update 2 from MSDN subscriber downloads.

If that doesn't work I'd suggest you ring Microsoft support directly and see if they can help you.

Comment: thanks.. I have uninstalled Update 3 and installed Update 2 CTP 2. It was not easy and straight forward but currently my tfs is back up. I will try a test machine and see what to do next ?

Comment: I installed the Update 2 but the DB upgrade always fails... I am screwed ... :(

Comment: Not quite screwed. Your option to progress now would be to create a new TFS 2012.3 machine and then use the TFS Integration Platform to migrate content between the servers.

Comment: Thanks for that info. will start looking intoit  and understand the tool to do the migration.

Comment: Took me a while to setup the test machine and all the tools to start the migration process. I am testing the first migration. Its going to take time since its rather a big one before i am confirm if it is going to succeed. Thanks again for directing me in this direction and hopefully this will win.

Comment: Have written a post on the same http://pumexintellecto.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/tfs-2012-express-ugrade-2-ctp-2-to-upgrade-3/